# html file and audio in the SVG tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to play a background audio in an HTML file (cannot be changed to svg file).

I also put my audio inside the `<svg>` tag (required).

```
<html>
        <svg>
            <audio id="backgroundmusic" loop>
                <source src="backgroundmusic.wav" type="audio/wav" />
            </audio>
        </svg>
</html>
```

Then, I use a function in other .js file to play the audio.

```
function playaudio(id){
var audiotesting = document.getElementById(id);
    audiotesting.currentTime = 0;
    audiotesting.play();
}
```

The function cannot work probably. Is there any method to play an audio inside `<svg>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, none of the Web APIs are tied to HTML specifically -- except classes like `HTMLDocument` and things that are directly related to HTML (`HTML*Element` classes), obviously. Otherwise, all APIs are available to the script interpreter, regardless of document type -- the `window` object and its `document` property, and all the rest of global classes, `HTMLDocument` included.

The JavaScript snippet you pasted would work with an SVG document hosting it just as well as with an HTML document. The problem lies with accessing the audio element -- where can it be embedded and located? `getElementById` would find it alright, but it would find it as an XML element with local name `audio`, it wouldn't know it was related to the HTML `audio` element, not at all. The element does not have `play` or `currentTime` properties.

With an SVG document you embed a script interpreter though the [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html#ScriptElement) element, much like with HTML.

However, you *cannot* simply put what I assume is the HTML `audio` element right inside an SVG, even an "inline" SVG document. You have at least two options though:

1. Embed the audio using the [`foreignObject`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement) facility in SVG:
2. Put the `audio` element *outside* SVG. If you only care about audio playback, and not the added convenience of the audio controls the browser typically may render, you'd be no worse off than having the element inside SVG. Ask yourself, why would you want the `audio` element inside the SVG in the first place?

Comment: thank you for your explanation and advising to use foreignObject.